# Running freeradius to handle WiFi access

Tags: session, freeradius

I’m a computer science teacher in a secondary school. The school has a simple network composed of 8 Unifi WiFi AP +  1 controller that supports radius authentication and accounting . Everything is directly connected to a single router (there are also 30 PC connected via eth cable) .

The WiFi network “should be” used exclusively by teachers (around 70) but systematically, some “clever” students, using some sort of social engineering attack, are always able to retrieve the WPA2 WiFi passphrase and access the network. Hence after a couple of week the network is saturated (there are 700 students in school!). For that reason I would like to move to WPA2 enterprise auth.

I’ve installed on an old machine a lubuntu distro with freeradius + MySQL + DaloRadius and everything seems to work properly, at least locally!.
In freeradius I created a group called “teacher” and I associated all the teachers to that group. That group has also the attribute “Simultaneous-Use := 1 “ in the radgroupcheck table , obviously every user/teacher has its own “Cleartext-Password” in the radcheck table.

**DESIRED REQUIREMENT:** I do not want a bullet proof wifi network but a reliable solution at least for teachers. I can accept the fact that, after an account violation, some students can by able to use the network (eg. 3-4 contemporary sessions), but massive usage of the WiFi network shall be avoided.

Here are my dubts:

- I’ve heard that ubiqui unifi hotspot are not so reliable in terms of accounting (sometime the session is not properly closed) so I could face some authentication problem also for the trusted user. According to the REQUIREMENT above, can I tune the freeradius attribute (Simultaneous-Use, Session Timeout, etc.) in order to avoid massive problem for teachers.
- Other suggestions? Eg. A schell script in cron to unlock the leftopen session after some time. Lease time tuning on DHCP.